# Iterating list and variable at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
num_of_class=5
num_of_division=[1,2,3,4,5]
for j, i in num_of_divisions, range(num_of_class):
    kiki=f"Class {i+1} has {j} divisions"
    print(kiki)
```

I'm expecting an output to be something like but I don't know how to get it. Need help with code for that.

```
Class 0 has 1 divisions
Class 1 has 2 divisions
Class 2 has 3 divisions
Class 3 has 4 divisions
Class 4 has 5 divisions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` to iterate over pairs of elements from two sequences in parallel:

```py
for j, i in zip(num_of_divisions, range(num_of_class)):
    # ...
```

Or when one is just a range of numbers, use `enumerate`:

```py
for i, j in enumerate(num_of_divisions,  1):
    # ...
```

The `1` here means `i` will start at 1, so you don't have to do `i+1`.